# JBOSS JMXInvokerServlet security access issue

Tags: jboss

Audit team raised below concerns about JMXInvoker servlet security access.

> "During our testing, we performed vulnerability scans and identified a Jboss server that did not require authentication to the JMXInvokerSerlet. It may be possible to exploit this in order to upload and execute arbitrary JSP pages to the server. We were unable to exploit this vulnerability"

Can anyone help us to propose a solution to make "http://ServerName:8080/invoker/JMXInvokerServlet" secure so that no one can have unauthorized access.

Answer (score 1):

To block the unauthorized access to the JMXInvokerServlet, I recommend you set a rule in your firewall to the internet to block access to the URL http:///invoker/JMXInvokerServlet. In order to run some internal tools, access is required to the JMXInvokerServlet, so blocking it at the edge of  your network will still allow users to run local tools on your intranet or over a VPN connection, while blocking malicious access from the internet.

If requiring access by local applications is not an issue, then following the instructions on the following web page (about halfway down the page, subtitle "Secure the JMX invokers")